# java.lang.RuntimeException: native snappy library not available: this version of libhadoop was built without snappy support

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am unable to fetch any data using below command in pyspark. Could you please help. I am using Cloudera VM 5.8.1 and Spark 1.6.0.

```
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
depts = sqlContext.sql("select * from departments")
for rec in depts.collect():
  print(rec)
```

Output

> java.lang.RuntimeException: native snappy library not available: this version of libhadoop was built without snappy support.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this `sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec","snappy")`
according to Cloudera [introduction](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/introduction_compression_snappy.html#concept_cy3_snz_pv)